# Set world border to 400 blocks

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to set the world border to 400 blocks when the server starts, so players can't go out of the map too far.

How can I achieve this? I can't find any way to do it myself.

Comment: Did you try to use barriers? http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Barrier

Answer (score 6):

To get a world, you could use [`Bukkit.getWorld(worldName)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Bukkit.html#getWorld(java.lang.String)). So, to get the world "world" (the default world), you could use:

```java
World world = Bukkit.getWorld("world");
```

Then, to get the [`WorldBorder`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/WorldBorder.html) of that world, you can use [`getWorldBorder()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/World.html#getWorldBorder()):

```java
WorldBorder border = world.getWorldBorder();
```

Then, you can modify the world to have a side length of 400 blocks by using:

```java
border.setSize(400.0);
```

and set the center to the location at `x = 0` and `z = 0` by using

```java
border.setCenter(0.0, 0.0);
```

So, the code in your `onEnable()` method in your `Main` class (the one that `extends JavaPlugin`) could look something like this:

```java
World world = Bukkit.getWorld("world");

WorldBorder border = world.getWorldBorder();
border.setSize(400.0);
border.setCenter(0.0, 0.0);
```

If you would like the border to be 400 blocks in every direction, you should set the size to `800.0` instead of `400.0`.

Comment: See also [`WorldBorder.setCenter(Location)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/WorldBorder.html#setCenter(org.bukkit.Location)).